# Mongoose won't populate an array or object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, schema, populate

Im having an issue where i have a Fixtures schema like so:

```
const FixtureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  home: {
    club: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'club'
    },
    score: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    scorers: [
      {
        player: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'player'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  away: {
    club: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'club'
    },
    score: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    scorers: [
      {
        player: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'player'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  match_num: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = Fixture = mongoose.model('fixture', FixtureSchema);
```

Club schema:

```
const ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Club = mongoose.model('club', ClubSchema);
```

Player Schema:

```
const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  club: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'club'
  },
  stats: {
    starts: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    goals: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    assists: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    goal_streak: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Player = mongoose.model('player', PlayerSchema);
```

I make a request like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fixture = await Fixture.find()
      .populate('player', ['name'])
      .populate('club', ['name']);
    res.json(fixture);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Postman get request gives me:

```
[
    {
        "home": {
            "score": 1,
            "club": "5e3dfcffb52ec61c30fc44cd",
            "scorers": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e4aac5d81d92b368398bd4d",
                    "player": "5e3dfddd4884f51cb7ee61e9"
                }
            ]
        },
        "away": {
            "score": 0,
            "club": "5e3dfd18b52ec61c30fc44ce",
            "scorers": []
        },
        "date": "2020-02-17T15:07:57.229Z",
        "_id": "5e4aac5d81d92b368398bd4c",
        "match_num": 1,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Why is it not populating the name of the player or the club??? It works when it is not stored in an array or object.. Ive tried looking for advice on other topics but cant find anything relating to this..

Thanks for any replies and advice

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the same as the other questions!!! lol..

If i change :

```
 .populate('club', ['name']);
```

to

```
.populate('home.club', ['name']);
```

and so on
it solves it...